# Given an integer s and a list of integers ints finding (x,y) in ints such that s = x + y

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

The following function `sum_pairs(ints, s)` takes two inputs: `ints` is a list with integer values and `s` is a integer number. The function `sum_pairs` returns the values `(x, y)` in `ints` such that \$s = x + y\$ and the index of `y` is the lowest for the `(x, y)` in `ints` such that \$s = x + y\$. This is a problem taken from *codewars*. The function passes all the test cases. However, when I attempt to run the code for a big list, the server *codewars* gives me the following answer: *"Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete"*.

I am wondering whether the code I have written to solve the problem can be optimised or should I use a different approach to give a solution.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):

    begin = 1
    end = len(ints)
    memo = []

    while begin < end:
        try:
            memo.append([begin-1, ints.index(s - ints[begin-1], begin, end)])
            begin += 1
            end = memo[-1][1]
        except:
            begin +=1

    if memo == []:
        return None
    else:
        return [ints[memo[-1][0]], ints[memo[-1][1]]]
```

The function `sum_pairs(ints, s)` searches for \$y = s - x\$ in the list `ints` using the function `index()`. If a value of `y` is found the index for the pair `(x,y)` is added to `memo`, then the range for the search `(begin, end)` are updated. Else only the lower limit `begin` for the search is updated.

Comment: sort and you should be able to do in in O(n logn)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code takes too long, because to check if a number is in array you use `.index`, effectively iterating over the whole array. However, since you need lots of these lookups, you can speed them up with more suitable data structure - `set` will do:

```
def sum_pairs_lookup(ints, s):
  waiting_for_pair = set()
  for y in ints:
    if (s - y) in waiting_for_pair:
      return [s - y, y]
  waiting_for_pair.add(y)
```

Also instead of looking for corresponding `y`, you can look for corresponding `x`, starting from the array's beginning. In this case the first match would give you the result.

[Run it online](https://repl.it/KBMn/2)

Edit: changed to accomodate points raised in comments, current version passes [tests](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/python)

Comment: @ Daerdemandt Beautiful ! it works like a charm, as  you have said. My first approach didn't perform very well not only because the data structure I used. I think the main problem was the O(^2) algorithm involved. If you need to look for a particular element on a data structure with a big number of elements do you think always it's a good idea to transform the problem in a `set` problem ?

Comment: @ Daerdemandt is there any faster that `a in set()`

Comment: @Masaguaro I wouldn't say `set` or `dict` are *always* the best solution, but quite often they are. Under the hood they are [hash-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which gives us sweet O(1) lookups [most of the time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). More than that, you should expect any collaborator to be familiar with them, so I think they (and their common [derivatives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)) should be the go-to solution. However, be aware of tradeoffs, sometimes, say, Bloom filter is what you need.

Answer (score 11):

Your code's complexity is \$O(n^2)\$, this means that worst case it's on-par with looping through `ints` in a nested loop, and returning the maximum for `x`, or the minimum for `y`. And so it's on-par with:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    try:
        return max(
            (x, y)
            for x in ints
            for y in ints
            if x + y = s
        )
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

You could speed this up, if `ints` is sorted, which your code implies, then you could change `max` to `next`, and flip the x and y. However, this still has \$O(n^2)\$ time.

The simplest way to force \$O(n)\$ time is to use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), and consume both ends of the sorted deque. This works by removing the tail of the deque to the point that \$x + y \le s\$. After this if \$x + y = s\$, then we return that. If not we take the next item at the head of the deque. Something like:

```
from collections import deque


def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    q = deque(ints)
    try:
        while True:
            y = q.popleft()
            n = s - y
            while q[-1] > n:
                q.pop()
            if q[-1] == n:
                return q[-1], y
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: Is normal control flow with exceptions considered normal / good style in Python?

Comment: @DanielJour It's not bad style - "[What is the EAFP principle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858)". But they can be slow, however since we go to the except one, if there are no matches, I don't think the clean-up speed matters too much here. In the code above not using exceptions would be harder to read IMO. I think using LBYL would also be slower here.

Comment: @peilonrayz is good idea to use more efficient data structures. However, If your run your script with `ints = [5, 3, 7, 7]` and `s = 10` the result will be None, but the right result for this case is `[3,7]`

Comment: @Masaguaro That as it assumes sorted input - "consume both ends of the sorted deque."

Comment: @Peilonrayz it needs always to take (consume) the left hand side element `x` of the list `ints` to combine with the right hand side element `y` of the list such as `y = s - x`. As you can see in the example that I gave you, for the first element `5` there is not an element `y` on the right hand side of the list such as `y = s -x`. So we need to keep those elements of the list to combine with the second element `3`, and so on.

Comment: @Masaguaro Again, the algorithm, as described in my answer, assumes the input is sorted.

Comment: @Masaguaro "I think to sort it must be very expensive", not really, it's \$O(n\log(n))\$, when using `sorted`. Your code is \$O(n^2)\$, to see this pass input where `y in q_set` is always false. Daerdemandt's answer is a much better base, if the data is unsorted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63535/discussion-between-masaguaro-and-peilonrayz).

Answer (score 1):

To expose more the logic, this is a list version code of the @Daerdemandt idea. Two lines shorter but not as fast as as it was required:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    for i in range(1,len(ints)):
        if (s - ints[i]) in ints[0:i]:
            return [s - ints[i], ints[i]]
```

Comment: Sorry @TobySpeight, perhaps i didn't do it right. It doesn't improve the solution. It's just another version using another data structure.... I can delete if it's necessary ..

Comment: The reasoning seems clear to me.